# Node - factory or constructor, or neither?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, module

I'm currently reading the node documentation on modules and came across this code.

The documentation says that the following is exporting a constructor function - yet there is no New keyword to instantiate the object. As a beginner this is confusing me a little. Is it a constructor?

And if so, why is there no New keyword? Thanks in advance.

```
//CODE USING MODULE

var square = require('./square.js');
var mySquare = square(2);
console.log('The area of my square is ' + mySquare.area());

// THE MODULE
// assigning to exports will not modify module, must use        module.exports

module.exports = function(width) {
  return {
    area: function() {
    return width * width;
   }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this example the author is simply referring to the pattern where one exports a top-level function from a module. You have to call this function when you require the module.  This top level function passes values in a closure to any functions it returns.

It might be clearer if you wrote the calling code like so:

```
var square = require('./square.js')(2);
square.area();
```

Compare this to the situation where the module doesn't return a top level function. The area function would need to be passed the width parameter:

```
var square = require('./square.js');
square.area(2);
```

The example is a bit contrived. Every function in the module gets access to the width variable. Big deal.  But imagine passing in something like a database connection.  You can see the pattern accomplishing much of the same thing as a constructor in an object oriented language, or indeed the way you construct javascript objects with the new keyword.

Comment: Thank you. Makes more sense to me now.